# How can I provide parameters when creating a child live view in Phoenix Live View?

Tags: phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

In a live view I have this snippet:

```html
  <div id="chat"><%= live_render(@socket, MyAppWeb.ChatLive.Index, id: "watch-chats", guest: @guest) %></div>
```

In ChatLive.Index I have this mount function:

```
  @impl true
  def mount(%{"guest_id" => guest_id}, _session, socket) do
    ...
  end

  def mount(:not_mounted_at_router, session, socket) do
    mount(%{"guest_id" => socket.assigns.guest.id}, session, socket)
  end
```

but it gives this error:

```
key :guest not found in: %{flash: %{}, live_action: nil}
```

at the line with `mount(%{"guest_id" => socket.assigns.guest.id}, session, socket)`.

How can I pass in a parameter such as guest to the `live_render` call and pick it up within the `mount` function?

Comment: If you need to pass data, you would need to put it in the assigns of the socket.

Comment: @franckstifler would you like to make that an answer?

Comment: Sure. Glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass data, you would need to put it in the assigns of the socket.

Answer (score -1):

You need to connect what you're passing into the `live_render` as params in the mount and then assign them to the socket if you need them available later.

Like this:

```html
  <div id="chat"><%= live_render(@socket, MyAppWeb.ChatLive.Index, id: "watch-chats", guest: @guest) %></div>
```

And then this:

```js
  def mount(%{"id" => id, "guest" => guest}, _session, socket) do
    ...
    new_socket = 
      socket
      |> assign(:id, id)
      |> assign(:guest, guest)
    {:ok, new_socket}
  end
```

Then those values should be available to pull from your socket object where ever it is.

But you could also store other values. If you only wanted to keep the guest_id and not the whole struct you could do:

```js
  def mount(%{"id" => id, "guest" => guest}, _session, socket) do
    ...
    new_socket = 
      socket
      |> assign(:id, id)
      |> assign(:guest_id, guest.id)
    {:ok, new_socket}
  end
```